# Transform $\Re(z)=1 \space , \Re(z)=\Im(z) \space and \space \Re(z)=-\Im(z)$ using the mapping $w=iz^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Can someone please verify whether i am doing this the right way -Thanks.

> $$w=iz^2=i(x^2+2xiy-y^2)=-2xy+i(x^2-y^2)$$

$$\color{green}{u=-2xy \tag{1}}$$ and $$\color{green}{v=x^2-y^2 \tag{2}}$$

> $\color{green}{1. \space Line \space \Re(z)=x=1}$

Substituting $x=1 \space in \space (1)$ we  get: $u=-2y \tag{i}$

$\Re(z)$ is on $x$ axis and therefore $y=0$ $\implies u = 0$.

$$(i) \implies \color{green}{y=-\dfrac{u}{2}}$$

Substituting $x=1 \space in \space (2)$ we  get: $v=1-y^2\tag{ii}$
using $(a)$ we get $v=1-\dfrac{u^2}{4}$

$$\color{green}{\therefore \Re(z)=1   \rightarrow u=0 \space and \space v=1-\dfrac{u^2}{4}}$$

> $\color{green}{2. \space Line \space \Re(z)=\Im(z) \implies y=x}$

for $x=y$ we get the following from $(1)$: $$u=-2x^2 \space \space or \space \space
 u=-2y^2$$

$$\implies u \le 0$$

for $x=y$ we get the following from $(2)$: $$v=0 $$

$$\color{green}{\therefore \Re(z)=\Im(z)   \rightarrow u \le 0 \space and \space v=0}$$

> $\color{green}{3. \space Line \space \Re(z)=\Im(z) \implies y=x}$

$v=0$ and $u \ge 0$

$$\color{green}{\therefore \Re(z)=-\Im(z)   \rightarrow u \ge 0 \space and \space v=0}$$

**EDIT:**

how does the transformed plot look like, is it just all the points $(u = -\infty ; v = 0) \space and \space (u = \infty ; v = 0) $ i.e. straight line on real axis and a parabola as in the picture below?

[image: Plot]

Comment: 2. = 3. (?) And in 2. You've written $u=0$ and $v=0$. This would mean that each point $z$ would be mapped onto $0$ which is not the case. (take for instance the point $z_0 = 1+i$ which gets mapped onto $w(z_0) = -1$.) The line $\operatorname{Re} z = \operatorname{Im} z$ gets mapped onto $\operatorname{Re} z <= 0$ and $\operatorname{Im} z = 0$. (= the interval ${]-\infty, 0]}$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i fixed $2.: u\le 0 ; v= 0$ and is this correct for $3. u \ge 0 ; v=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's looking good.

Comment: how would the plot of the transformed region look like, does $u \le 0 ; v=0$ and $u \ge 0 ; v =0$ imply that region maps to all those points $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(\infty; 0)$ i.e a line or do we have something like this ![here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CwINS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. and 3. look fine, but 1. has some small (notation) error(s):

You write:

- "...$\operatorname{Re}(z)$ is on $x$-axis and therefore $y=0$ ..."

  What do you mean here?
- $u=0$ is not true. Since $y\in \mathbb{R}\Rightarrow u =-2y \in \mathbb{R}$.

  Neither is this consistent with the picture you drew. (in that curve $u$ clearly travels through $\mathbb{R}$)

Aside from the small notation errors I find it difficult to read, because you use all those references. I would write it as follows:

$$\operatorname{Re} z = 1 \leftrightarrow z(y) = 1+iy \qquad y\in \mathbb{R}$$

Then:

$$\begin{align}
w(z) = iz^2 &= i(1+iy)^2\\
& = i(1+2iy-y^2)\\
&= -2y +i (1-y^2)\\
\end{align}$$

Meaning $$u= -2y\qquad v=1-y^2$$

It's easier to work with parameterizations. The same is valid for 2. and 3. As an example

$$\operatorname{Re}z = \operatorname{Im} z \leftrightarrow z(x) = x+ix \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}$$

The plots look good.